# Automatically Creating Pages on the Server When an Entry in a Database is Created

Tags: database

Using PHP, does anyone know how to make it so that when someone registers on a website (and therefore enters data into a database), a folder with a default php file is created on the web root/server???

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good design.  Rather, you should have your PHP files look at the session to find the logged in user's id, and query the necessary data about that user id.  You don't need a file for each user.  You can make your table auto-increment a user id.